# Why do fonts in Chrome appear smaller in development than in production?

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js

I have a vue js app, that when viewed locally in Chrome on Windows, the text has a particular size. When I view it in production, it looks bigger. I verified that the CSS is identical (as it should be) via dev tools.

This is not the case for:

Chrome on Ubuntu
Firefox, in either Windows or Ubuntu
Edge on Windows

In all these cases, the font size is the same in development and in production. What could be the explanation?

Comment: Have you accidentally increased the browser zoom for the production website? Otherwise, you could compare the `font-size` on a specific element rather than checking the CSS file in case it's getting it from cache.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Wasn't aware of this "zoom" feature. It was the dev version that had reduced zoom, and it appears to be persistent for the particular url. Thx.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you accidentally increased the browser zoom for the production website?

Otherwise, you could compare the font-size on a specific element rather than checking the CSS file in case it's getting it from cache.